# Python zero leading error

Tags: python

Столкнулся с ошибкой leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted при попытке использовать числа начинающиеся с нуля в следующей функции:

```
def onebit(n:int):
    n1 = str(n)
    pre = n1.replace('0','')
    ans = len(pre)
    return ans
```

На leetcode в примере используются 32-ух значные числа начинающиеся с нуля. Прошу помочь с данным вопросом.

Comment: Эта функция не должна ругаться с такой ошибкой. Почему вы уверены что исключение возникает в ней? Эти 32-значные числа в литкоде скорее всего в двоичной системе исчисления. Вы в этой функции манипулируете десятичными целыми числами. Я пока связь не уловил.

Comment: Как именно вы вызываете данную функцию? Если вот так `onebit(0001)`, то это к функции вообще отношения не имеет, так будет такая же ошибка: `x = 0001`.